# How to make data request complete and load animation disappear

Tags: angular, typescript

```
enter code here`
     ngOnInit() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.jobExecution$ = this.route.params
          .pipe(mergeMap(
            val => this.jobsService.getJobExecution(val.id)
          ),
          catchError((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            if (HttpAppError.is404(error) || HttpAppError.is400(error)) {
              this.loading = false;
              this.cancel();
            }
            this.loggerService.log('error while loading Job Execution Details', error);
            this.loading = false;
            this.notificationService.error('错误', 'error');
            return EMPTY;
          }));
      }`
```

How to make data request complete and load animation disappear？
The code that cancels the animation and disappears doesn't know where to add it.

Comment: You can use `tap` function. It handles next, error and complete event.

Comment: I don't know how to change it. Can you be specific? Thanks very much.

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: I tried your method, but I still couldn't.,I think it's a dirty test problem, but I'm a novice. I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: your problem is somewhere else, we need more code to help you

Comment: Okay, I'll show you more code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **tap** (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html)

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.jobExecution$ = this.route.params
          .pipe(mergeMap(
            val => this.jobsService.getJobExecution(val.id)
          ),
          tap(
            (next) => (this.loading = false),
            (error) => {
              console.log(error);
            if (HttpAppError.is404(error) || HttpAppError.is400(error)) {
              this.cancel();
            }
            this.loggerService.log('error while loading Job Execution Details', error);
            this.loading = false;
            this.notificationService.error('错误', 'error');
            return EMPTY;
            },
          ));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tested that loading animations sometimes disappeared and sometimes did not disappear.

Comment: You should create a https://stackblitz.com/ or edit your question and add your whole code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll try it.

Comment: I tested it again in your way. I'm glad it succeeded. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @liumengyang glad it worked well for you. Consider accept the answer if your problem is solved !

Answer (score 2):

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = false;  //*always disable loader on ngOnInit
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(){
    this.loading = true;  //correct
    this.jobExecution$ = this.route.params
    .pipe(mergeMap(
      val => this.jobsService.getJobExecution(val.id)
    ).then( //on success
      this.loading = false; //***disable loader in here too
    ),
    catchError((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      if (HttpAppError.is404(error) || HttpAppError.is400(error)) {
        this.loading = false; //correct
        this.cancel();
      }
      this.loggerService.log('error while loading Job Execution Details', error);
      this.loading = false; //correct
      this.notificationService.error('错误', 'error');
      return EMPTY;
    }));
  }
```

Try this way. Follow best practices.
Also disable loader on successfull response.

Comment: Are you sure you can use `then` on rxjs observables ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tested that loading animations sometimes disappeared and sometimes did not disappear.

Comment: Determine that rxjs can be used

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I would prefer to use *finalize* because it runs when the observable complete (on success or on error)
See: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;

    this.jobExecution$ = this.route.params
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(val => this.jobsService.getJobExecution(val.id)),
        catchError((error) => {
          if (HttpAppError.is404(error) || HttpAppError.is400(error)) {
            this.cancel();
          }

          this.loggerService.log('error while loading Job Execution Details', error);
          this.notificationService.error('错误', 'error');
          return EMPTY;
        }),
        finalize(() => this.loading = false)
      )
   );
}
```

Comment: I tried your method, but I still couldn't.,I think it's a dirty test problem, but I'm a novice. I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: If nothing change, you can trigger a refresh of your view by using the ChangeDetectorRef see: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Import the ChangeDetectorRef in your component, and in the finalize use: this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()